# What is the consequence of not normalizing test data after training a convolutional neural network

Tags: neural-network

To the best of my knowledge the normalization mainly facilitates the training(optimization) phase. If I train a network with normalized data sets but later feed it unnormalized test data, what will be the theoretical consequence? e.g. Will the test accuracy be bad?

I've done an experiment of this on cifar-10 and found that the network still gives good results on those unnormalized test data.